# In knex, how to access column value in a join without raw?

Tags: knex.js

With knex, is it possible to do this without `raw`?

```
q.leftJoin('columnName as cn', raw('?? is true', ['cn.bool']))
```

I tried

```
q.leftJoin('columnName as cn', b => {
  b.on('cn.bool', 'is', 'true')
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make it without `raw`, since the default behavior of `join` in next is to join by 2 columns and not by **value**.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onVal`

```
q.leftJoin('columnName as cn', b => {
  b.onVal('cn.bool', 'true')
}
```

Its not a well documented feature